# [Error] nodelet pcl/* crash

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-groovy, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've switch to Groovy and we i tried to run my launch file with calls a pcl nodelet, the nodelet crashes.

I tried to load it manualy (command-line) and i'm getting the same error.

I do

```
$ rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager
```

And get

```
[ INFO] [1360435647.453864706]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
```

all OK.

In another terminal i run:

```
$ rosrun nodelet nodelet load pcl/PassThrough nodelet_manager ~input:="/camera/depth_registered/points"
```

and i get:

```
[ INFO] [1360435704.541942377]: Loading nodelet /pcl_PassThrough of type pcl/PassThrough to manager nodelet_manager with the following remappings:
[ INFO] [1360435704.542172024]: /pcl_PassThrough/input -> /camera/depth_registered/points
[FATAL] [1360435704.550783258]: Service call failed!
```

and on the 1st terminal (nodelet manager) i get

```
[ERROR] [1360435704.550185447, 1358879347.082131986]: Failed to load nodelet [/pcl_PassThrough] of type [pcl/PassThrough]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pcl/PassThrough with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2
```

This happens even without running anything that publish the /camera/depth_registered/points. I can make this happen with just 3 terminals, the roscore and the two i described here.

Also this happens for the Passtrough, VoxelGrid, StatisticalOutlierRemoval

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54821/%5Berror%5D-nodelet-pcl/*-crash/) by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-04**:
I get the same error using the very latest Groovy debs (pushed just last night) and Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  Everything was working fine under Fuerte.  Ticket submitted here https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has now been fixed in the latest Groovy debs.  See the (now closed) ticket at: [https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/7.](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/7)

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1